# I want to set flag in android application which retain its value even forced close the app

Tags: android

I have some settings in the Application which I want to retain even when I am forced close the application . i.e. I want to maintain the flag value even after closing the application.

How can I do it. I am new in android. if any sample code, it will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use SharedPreferences, here's the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class to store simple scalar data such as flags.